# How to instantiate a collection of type MyCollection<T> : IList<Alert<T>>?

Tags: c#, generics, collections, c#-4.0

I have an `Alert <T>` object.
suppose I want to get all the alerts for type MyObject, 
I would have a collection of type 
`MyCollection<MyObject> : IList<Alert<MyObject>>`.

How would I implement methods for that list?

Comment: If you want to hide Alert, why derive from IList and not a concrete instance already, like: public class MyCollection<T> : List<Alert<T>>{ }

Answer (score 1):

Let me first ask you, why build your own custom collection? Do you really need it? If so you might want to take a look at MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xth2y6ft(VS.71).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182132(VS.80).aspx), if not use any of the generic collection classes that are already in the framework.

Comment: The important thing is to have a generic type alert..
As far as the list is concerned i'm not that sure whats the best solution, AFAIK it could be 'List<Alert<MyObject>>>'..

My question though is more basic to how to create a list of 'Alert<MyObject>>' from 'var allobjects = dbcontext.????'

Comment: Hi Benny,

It seems I had to review the way I implemented my alert object, And since it is susceptible to frequent changes Generics may not be the best way to go about it. 
So instead of Alert<T>
Id go for
 class Alert {
public AlertObject Item {get;set;} //type enum
public int ObjectID {get;set;}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the solution should be some sort of dynamic constructor..

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution though I hav'nt had a chance to test it yet.

```
public class Base
{

    private delegate Base ConstructorDelegate(int someParam);

    public class ClassReference
    {
        Type currentType = typeof(Base);

        public Base Create<U>() where U : Base
        {
            ConstructorInfo ci = currentType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance |
            BindingFlags.Public, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
            DynamicMethod dm = new DynamicMethod("CreateInstance", typeof(Base), Type.EmptyTypes, typeof(ClassReference));
            ILGenerator il = dm.GetILGenerator();
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ci);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            ConstructorDelegate del = (ConstructorDelegate)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(ConstructorDelegate));
            return del();
        }

        public Base Create<U>(int someParam) where U : Base
        {
            ConstructorInfo ci = currentType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance |
            BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[] { typeof(int) }, null);
            DynamicMethod dm = new DynamicMethod("CreateInstance", typeof(Base), new Type[] {
            typeof(int) }, typeof(ClassReference));
            ILGenerator il = dm.GetILGenerator();
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ci);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            ConstructorDelegate del = (ConstructorDelegate)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(ConstructorDelegate));
            return del(someParam);
        }

        private ClassReference(Type type)
        {
            currentType = type;
        }
        internal ClassReference() { }

        public static implicit operator ClassReference(Type input)
        {
            if (!typeof(Base).IsAssignableFrom(input))
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Type {0} must derive from {1}", input,
                typeof(Base)));
            return new ClassReference(input);
        }
    }


}
```

[by Joanna Carter's c# version of
 Delphis Meta Class](http://www.prototypical.co.uk/pdf/c%23class.pdf)

Comment: This seems like a good solution and I get all the types into Base..

It seems like this will save me writing a lot of code.. 
Has anyone ever used this type of solution? what do you think?

I will appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an important piece of what im looking for:

```
 entityObject = objectContext.GetEntityByKey<T>(id);
```

a generic method for getting the entities from the datacontext